# Swift local notification custom alert sound with label.text value

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I am trying to implement label text read and assign to local notification sound. Whenever local notification trigger It should make sound like "Hey your +label.text+ file downloaded.

Please help me to make above scenarion.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.body = "Body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TestIdentifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

I have text to speech but I don't how to merge both

```
import AVFoundation

let string = "Hello, World!"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synth.speak(utterance)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like possible in iOS. Custom notification sound should be an instance of the `UNNotificationSound` class, `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice` can't help you with this.

```
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: soundName)
```

Please check below link. [raywenderlich](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/play-avspeechutterance-in-local-notification-swift3/32006)

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmennis/the-3-ps-to-custom-alert-sounds-in-ios-push-notifications-9ea2a2956c11

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.